# AWK split column, count occurrences of second split variable

Tags: awk, split

I would like to use awk to split column one of a file by "(" and count the number of occurrences of each of the second variables of the split command.

```
cluster1(2 genes, 2 taxa):  column2 column 3
cluster1(2 genes, 2 taxa):  column2 column 3
cluster1(3 genes, 2 taxa):  column2 column 3
cluster1(3 genes, 2 taxa):  column2 column 3
cluster1(4 genes, 2 taxa):  column2 column 3
```

So my output would be

```
2 genes, 2 taxa = 2
3 genes, 2 taxa = 2
4 genes, 2 taxa = 1
```

Thank you for your help,
Kate

Comment: so what did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -F '[()]' '{arr[$2]++} END{for(i in arr) print i " = " arr[i]}' data 
4 genes, 2 taxa = 1
3 genes, 2 taxa = 2
2 genes, 2 taxa = 2
```

or a pipeline counting using `uniq`:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=\().*(?=\))' data | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,$3,$4,$5 " =",$1}'
2 genes, 2 taxa = 2
3 genes, 2 taxa = 2
4 genes, 2 taxa = 1
```